# how to load the datatemplate in a listbox as per the number of data in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

i have a task list in xml file,i want it to bind it to the label,one after the other on each label in each template,i am unable to load the template as per the number of task in xml file.,the number of task should be equal to number of templates and the label should contain the name of the task,i m stuck here is the code for data template

```
 <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="tasktemplate1">
                <Canvas Height="50" Width="850">
                    <Label   Height="30" Width="170" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="130" Background="LightGray">
                    </Label>
                    <TextBox Height="30" Width="120" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="370" Background="LightBlue"></TextBox>
                    <Label Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="10">$</Label>
                    <Button Click="deletebuttonclick" Canvas.Top="12" Height="10" Width="30" Canvas.Left="600" ></Button>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
```

for the listbox code is like this

```
 <TabItem>
        <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">

            <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}"  x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850">
            </ListBox>
            <Label Canvas.Top="-18" Canvas.Left="185">Select Task</Label>
            <Label Canvas.Top="-18" Canvas.Left="377" RenderTransformOrigin="0.58,0.462">Enter Bill Rates</Label>
            <Button Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="575" Width="139">Click to add the task</Button>
        </Canvas>
    </TabItem>
```

currently i am binding it to a namelist i have manually created the behind code is so depending on this code 4 datatemplates are created,but i am not able to get the task from xml file on my label of the template

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.Load("http://store.tymesheet.com/templates/Software-Developer.xml");
        XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Tasks/task");
        string temp=null;
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            temp = node["name"].InnerText;
        }

        _nameList = new List<string>
                    {
                      "1",
                      "2",
                      "3",
                      "4",
                    };
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private List<string> _nameList;
    public List<string> NameList
    {
        get { return _nameList; }
    }
```

the screenshot for xml file is
[image]

the screen shot of the look of my template is here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get **`name`** of task, you can do that directly in XAML only using **`XmlDataProvider`** which will act as **`ItemsSource`** for your ListBox.

```
<Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Tasks" XPath="tasks"
           Source="http://store.tymesheet.com/templates/Software-Developer.xml"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tasktemplate1">
            <Canvas Height="50" Width="850" Background="lightgray">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=name}" Height="30"
                       Width="170" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="150" 
                       Background="LightGray"/>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="60" Canvas.Top="10"
                         Canvas.Left="370" Background="Black"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="10">$</Label>
                <Button Click="deletebuttonclick" 
                        Canvas.Top="12" Height="10" Width="30"
                        Canvas.Left="600"/> 
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildNodes, Source={StaticResource Tasks}}" 
          x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850"/>
    ....
</Canvas>
```

Set Path to **`ChildNodes`** and in Label bind **`XPath`** to **`name`**.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to do it in code behind, you have to fill the list and set ItemsSource to be that list. *(Make sure you add namespace **System.Linq** to use extension methods like Select, OfType etc.)*

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://store.tymesheet.com/templates/Software-Developer.xml");
var taskList = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
               .Where(node => node.Name == "tasks")
               .SelectMany(node => node.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>())
               .Select(node => node["name"].InnerText);
listBox.ItemsSource = taskList;
```

and in *XAML*:

bind label Content to Binding like this:

```
<Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tasktemplate1">
            <Canvas Height="50" Width="850" Background="lightgray">
                <Label Content="{Binding}"      <-- HERE
                       Height="30" Width="170"
                       Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="150"
                       Background="LightGray"/>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="60" Canvas.Top="10"
                         Canvas.Left="370" 
                         Background="Black"/>
                <Label Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="10">$</Label>
                <Button Click="deletebuttonclick" Canvas.Top="12" Height="10" 
                        Width="30" Canvas.Left="600"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}"
                x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850"/>
    ....
</Canvas>
```

Comment: than wat about the number of templates getting created?will it be exactly the same as the number of task in xml file?

Comment: yup since I have binded to ChildNodes collection so it will be equal to number of task in the collection. In XML you provided this will show 11 task.

Comment: I have updated with code behind approach as well. See if that helps.

Comment: Create a List and remove item from that list and assign back ItemsSource of listBox. OR if you use proper bindings using `ObservableCollection`, simply removing item from the list will update the UI. (Remove item from the list which you want to remove from UI).

Comment: help me on a question i have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285863/how-to-get-the-label-content-from-a-list-box